# Is my fan running constantly dangerous?

Tags: cpu, fan, hp-laptop

My CPU can be at 2% with a CPU temperature of 30° and the fan is still running. The fan speed is usually between 1700 and 1800 (1800 is shown at max fan speed). My laptop is only a few months old and I'm not completely sure whether it has always been running. **Is it dangerous for my fan to constantly be running? Could it cause long term hardware issues?** I sent my laptop back to HP because of this and they said my fan was replaced but it still runs constantly with the same noise as before.

Comment: CPU's heat very quickly in very localized places, but they also pass on that heat quickly, if a proper heatsink is used, but over time, that heatsink must exchange heat to air proportionately in order to keep taking heat from the CPU. As such, your Fan should always be running, but the PWM features should run it at an appropriate RPM for your fan diameter, air intake, and exhaust volumes. Note that for a small diameter fan, your RPMs are low, but for a higher diameter fan, they are potentially moderate.for instance a 10mm fan will usually run at low at about 1700 RMP.

Comment: @Frank Thomas how can I find out the diameter of my fan? This is in a laptop so I assume the diameter is low but I don't know.

Comment: You normally cannot change the fan size in a laptop, so it is what HP designed it.

Comment: HP's take is don't worry about it. you can probably find out if you like by trolling the after market parts sites, but HP commonly does not expose PWM or related config. I'm actually surprised you are getting clean accurate reads off your sensors. that's really hit and miss with laptops. consider yourself lucky that your cooling is more aggressive than you need rather than less. My last HP laptop would start to slow well before the cooling kicked into high gear, and support had no answers for me in terms of configuring it to taste.

Comment: @Frank Thomas I don't know how accurate the readings are as I'm using a third party app. I am happy if it will keep my laptop running smoothly (which it has been) but I just didn't know if it was dangerous for the health of the fan in the long run.

Comment: It is not dangerous for the health of the Fan as it was designed to run. It appears your machine is running as designed .

Comment: you should be fine. also keep in mind. laptops don't have the expected lifespans of desktops, so while some folks get lucky and keep one running for 6+ years, you should really expect to replace them every 3-4 years if they are used regularly or are not properly stored when not in use.

Comment: @Frank Thomas yeah that's not a problem I usually replace it every 2ish years from general wear and tear eg scratches on the body, performance slowing over time.

Comment: @John okay great, as long as it's running as normal I'm happy, just overly vigilant about tech because I'm not very good with it.

Comment: Your computer is designed that way, so it appears to be running normally, and then that is the way it is for you. No need to worry about it at all. I amended my answer with extra information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The Fan in a good laptop can run forever at lowest speed (I think your speed above is low speed).

All my laptops going back some years have CPUs that pick their speed according to load and the Fan works with that.

No danger in having the Fan run continuously on low and speed up when needed.

**Note:** Laptop manufacturers design the cooling system in their machines. So you have to live with what the manufacturer offers. Do not try to turn the fan off because the CPU could quickly overheat.

I should note that I serviced a ThinkPad with a Fan error. The machine would start, the Fan stopped and the machine shut down instantly.

No needed to worry about your fan running all the time and indeed, take comfort in it.

Comment: Okay great, yeah the fan is quiet enough but definitely hearable, not a massive annoyance though because I don't have to use it too often. So it probably isn't a sign something is wrong? I did send it to HP and they replaced the fan but I have a small suspicion they didn't check if there were any other issues.

Comment: If HP replaced the Fan because it was noisy, then you should be fine.  It will still run all the time. It should be almost inaudible at low speed. I can just barely hear my Fan running. It is not annoying. It is not at all dangerous to run all the time.

Comment: it is pretty audible, it's not something I have to listen out for and if I'm sat in front of it with no other noise around me or from the speakers I can hear it pretty well, but it is much quieter than when there is high CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

Most HP laptops have a fan always on setting in the BIOS/UEFI. It's enabled by default by design and isn't dangerous. Having it always on helps keep the laptop extra cool when the CPU is idle.

You may be able to turn this setting off if you find it annoying by restarting Windows then repeatedly press <kbd>ESC</kbd> as soon as the screen goes black until the Startup Menu appears. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> for `BIOS setup`. You should find the `Fan Always On` setting which is usually found under `System Configuration`.

Comment: I don't really care about how annoying the noise is, my headphones can block it out really easily. I'll check if this setting is on later though just to make sure that's what's happening, if it isn't I'll update you.